# Serving Images over Websockets with NodeJS & SocketIO

Tags: node.js, websocket, socket.io

I am trying to develop a very simple image server with NodeJS & SocketIO.  A project I am working on requires me to load several hundred images on page-load (customer requirement).  Currently, a HTTP request is made for each image via use of the HTML "img" tag.  With the reduced latency and overall efficiency of websockets compared to HTTP or Ajax, I was hoping to improve performance by sending images over websockets instead.

Unfortunately, reading images from the server's file-system with NodeJS and sending them over websockets with SocketIO has been significantly slower than the traditional HTTP requests served over Apache.  Below is my server code:

```
var express = require('express'),
    app = express(),
    http = require('http'),
    fs = require("fs"),
    mime = require('mime'),
    server = http.createServer(app),
    io = require('socket.io').listen(server);

server.listen(151);

io.sockets.on('connection',function(socket){
    socket.emit('connected');

    socket.on('getImageData',function(file,callback){
        var path = 'c:/restricted_dir/'+file;

        fs.readFile(path,function(err,data){
            if (!err){
                var prefix = "data:" + mime.lookup(path) + ";base64,";
                var base64Image = prefix+data.toString('base64');
                socket.emit('imageData',data,callback);
            }
        });
    });
});
```

I have also tried buffering with "createReadStream", but I saw no significant speed improvements with this.  I should also note that it is desirable to receive the image data as a Base64-encoded dataURI so I can simply throw that into the "src" attribute of the "img" tag.  I understand Base64 means roughly a 30% increase in the data's size, but even when using binary image data, it still takes about 10 times longer than HTTP.

**EDIT:**
I suppose the real question here is, "are websockets really the best way to serve static files?"  After further thought and additional reading, I strongly suspect the issue here is related to parallel processing.  Since NodeJS operates on a single thread, maybe it is not the best solution for serving all these static image files?  Does anyone have any thoughts on this?

Comment: what does your client side code look like?

Comment: Nothing special on the client side.  Standard Socket.IO connection code then a loop around an array of filenames calling the following code: socket.emit('getImageData',file,callback);

The callback simply throws the response data into image tags and appends them on the page.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Browsers usually open multiple connections to the same server to perform requests in parallel, and can also perform [multiple requests per single connection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_persistent_connection), whereas you only have one websocket connection.

Also, the combo `fs.readFile()/Base64-encode/socket.emit()` introduces a significant overhead, where a regular httpd can use system calls like [`sendfile()`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/sendfile.2.html) and don't even have to touch the file contents before they are being sent to the client.

The single-threaded nature of Node isn't an issue here, because Node can do I/O (which is what you're doing, minus the Base64-encoding) really well.

So I would say that websockets aren't very suitable for static file serving :)

Comment: I was under the impression the browser could only have 2 HTTP connections open at one time for a specific page, glad to see that's changed.  It definitely makes sense that NodeJS introduces overhead from the actual file-parsing.  If I don't just walk away defeated and stick with HTTP, I think might check out the SPDY protocol.  Thanks for your answer!

Comment: @CauselessEffect the number of connections a browser opens to the same host differs between browsers (see [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/985704/893780) for an overview; the HTTP RFC states that at most 2 persistent connections per host should be opened); but still, it can perform multiple requests per single connection.